# How to modify this code so that the first derivative image of the function displays different colors above and below the x-axis?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

```
ClearAll["`*"];
f[x_] := x^3 - 5 x - 10
D[f[x], x] // FullSimplify
xr = -5 <= x <= 5
Solve[D[f[x], x] == 0, x, Reals]
NSolve[D[f[x], x] == 0 && xr, x, Reals]
gmax = Maximize[{f[x], xr}, x]
gmin = Minimize[{f[x], xr}, x]
lmax = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] < 0, xr}, x]
lmaxv = {x, f[x]} /. lmax[[1]] // FullSimplify
lmin = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] > 0, xr}, x]
lminv = {x, f[x]} /. lmin[[1]] // FullSimplify
Manipulate[
 Refresh[functions = 
   Table[D[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, nMax, 1}] // FullSimplify;
  orders = 
   Table[D[f[x], {x, n}] // Inactivate // TraditionalForm // 
     ToString, {n, 0, nMax, 1}];
  labels = 
   MapThread[#1 <> " = " <> ToString[#2, TraditionalForm] &, {orders, 
     functions}];];
 Plot[{functions}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  Epilog -> {{Darker@Purple, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
     Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]], AbsolutePointSize[7], Red, 
     Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]]}, {Darker@Red, 
     AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]], 
     AbsolutePointSize[7], Black, Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]]}, 
    AbsolutePointSize[8], Green, Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmin], Red, 
    Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmax]}, PlotLabels -> labels, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"f(x) = ", f[x]}]], {{nMax, 1, "Order"}, 1, 10, 1,
   PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

How to modify this code so that the first derivative image of the function displays different colors above and below the x-axis?

Update 1 based on kglr:

```
ClearAll["`*"];
f[x_] := x^3 - 5 x - 10
D[f[x], x] // FullSimplify
xr = -5 <= x <= 5
Solve[D[f[x], x] == 0, x, Reals]
NSolve[D[f[x], x] == 0 && xr, x, Reals]
gmax = Maximize[{f[x], xr}, x]
gmin = Minimize[{f[x], xr}, x]
lmax = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] < 0, xr}, x]
lmaxv = {x, f[x]} /. lmax[[1]] // FullSimplify
lmin = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] > 0, xr}, x]
lminv = {x, f[x]} /. lmin[[1]] // FullSimplify
Manipulate[
 Refresh[functions = 
   Table[D[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, nMax, 1}] // FullSimplify;
  orders = 
   Table[D[f[x], {x, n}] // Inactivate // TraditionalForm // 
     ToString, {n, 0, nMax, 1}];
  labels = 
   MapThread[#1 <> " = " <> ToString[#2, TraditionalForm] &, {orders, 
     functions}];];
 Plot[Evaluate@
   Append[functions, 
    Style[ConditionalExpression[functions[[2]], functions[[2]] <= 0], 
     RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]], {x, -5, 5}, 
  Epilog -> {{Darker@Purple, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
     Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]], AbsolutePointSize[7], Red, 
     Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]]}, {Darker@Red, 
     AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]], 
     AbsolutePointSize[7], Black, Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]]}, 
    AbsolutePointSize[8], Black, Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmin], Red, 
    Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmax]}, PlotLabels -> labels, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"f(x) = ", f[x]}]], {{nMax, 1, "Order"}, 1, 10, 1,
   PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your code gives error when run as is on V 13.2.1, here is a screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYvCU.png)   also, it would be better to make a smaller example of what you want to do instead of larger code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: The function has been replaced because the code calculates the global maximum and global minimum values of the function within a certain interval. local Maximum and local minimum values. But not all functions have corresponding values, so there may be errors. Now that I have corrected it, there is no problem with this error report.

Comment: Probably there's a solution on site since there's one for the second derivative, which you might adapt: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258120/plot-that-changes-color-depending-on-whether-fx0/258124#258124

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `{functions}` in the first argument of `Plot` with

```
Evaluate @ Append[functions, 
   Style[ConditionalExpression[functions[[2]], functions[[2]] <= 0], Cyan]]
```

to get

[image]

Replace `Cyan` with `Directive[White, Dashed]` to get

[image]